# Exception.Data population bug?

Tags: .net, exception

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    adapter.Fill(table);

    return;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    SqlException sqlEx = ex as SqlException;
```

I have an exception that's being thrown by adapter.Fill(), and when I put a breakpoint on the first line in the exception handler, the Exception.Data property already contains a key that is unique to my application.

The thing is that it does not happen every time, but only when this exception is thrown within ~2 seconds of it last being thrown.

Explain that!!

Comment: Need more info, and possibly the exception thrown. Also more backgroupd info would be mucha appreciated.

Comment: @Obalix- the particular SqlException is number #4060 (login failed).

Comment: Maybe start with describing what you call the first line of the handler, and why it shouldn't have that Id.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you quoted I would assume that the SQL Connection information you are using is not correct, or that the password has expired. Check your connection and test it outside your environment.

If you are using integrated security, it could possible be that the user is not added to the SQL Server security, or the user does not have access to the database. In SQl Server security is a two step process, first add the user to the SQL Server as a valid login and then grant the user access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment on this [page](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/24/.Net-Passing-user-data-with-Exception-back-to-the-caller.aspx) that sounds like it may pertain to what you are seeing.

The user (TWheelhouse) said:

> It appears on the surface that somehow
>   certain .NET framework features try to
>   re-use instances of an exception,
>   causing flags added to the 'Data'
>   collection to appear to have been set
>   when they are really just hanging
>   around from a previous time when the
>   exception was thrown and the flag
>   added...

```
public static void foo(string connectionString) {
  try {
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection (connectionString);
    cn.Open();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex) {
    if (ex.Data.Contains("MY_TEST_FLAG"))
      Debug.WriteLine("BAD! It Shouldn't be there yet!");
    else
      Debug.WriteLine("Fine.");

    ex.Data.Add("MY_TEST_FLAG", true);
  }
}
```

> Call foo() several times with a
>   connection string that is vaild in
>   format, but with perhaps a bad UID
>   value. The first time you call FOO, I
>   get the "Fine." message when the bad
>   connection string causes the
>   Connection object to throw a
>   SqlException, but each time after
>   that, I get the "BAD!" message (for a
>   while, eventually I'll get a "Fine"
>   message again, once, then more "BAD!"
>   messages).
>
> If each time I try to create a
>   SqlConnection with a bad connection
>   string were really resulting in
>   completely unique instances of
>   SqlException to be thrown, I'd get the
>   "Fine" message every time!

I have not replicated this issue myself, nor attempted to run the code above, but it seemed like it might be connected to your reported problem.